# I want to make pagination between text file and mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, database, text, pagination

I've commenting based reviews system. I want amendment in my system

Right now We fetched data from both data sources **TEXT FILE** and **MYSQL DB**.

Mysql pagination is created, Now I've bit different scenario. I want to fetch first 6 pages data from mysql database and after 6 pages fetch data from text file

Example 1 : first 6 pages have 42 records from mysql and then 7 page show record from text file.

one more thing right now user entering comment and data stored in database it is working perfectly but about pagination. If we are getting any new comment from user then we need to extend pagination

Example 2 : 42 records from mysql then we get new one comment review and store in database then database have 43 record.

The Simple question is we need to start pagination from database and end to text file.

simple example : 1 to 6 pages show data from database and from page 7 show data from Text file

Comment: Why you are asking like this? is it possible or not?

Comment: Could you please explain a little more your last sentence ? I don't understand your need.

Comment: Thanks Alexandre I want to make pagination using mysql database and text file. but start data from mysql and end data from txt file